# Animate a moving rect over a static image Java SWT

Tags: java, animation, swt

I am trying to learn Java by animating an moving object over an static image. My image is drawn in a Canvas and everything is drawn inside a

```
   canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent e){
       //Do Stuff
}
```

I am stuck at how to call an Timer to draw my object of "moving rect". Do I place it inside "moving rect" class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `timerExec` method of `Display` to schedule a `Runnable` to run after a delay. The `Runnable` can redraw the control.

For example:

```java
canvas.getDisplay().timerExec(100, () -> canvas.redraw());
```

will call the `redraw` method after a delay of 100 milliseconds (code uses a Java 8 lambda for the `Runnable`). You could call this at the end of the `paintControl` method.

Comment: Worked perfectly. But I would  like to ask if the approach is correct for redrawing only the "moving rect" .Since inside my canvas painControl I would draw lots of static things and i mean those static thing got redraw too

Comment: You should only draw in the paint listener. Trying to redraw selectively is difficult since in some cases the canvas may need to be completely redrawn. There is a `redraw(x, y, width, heigth, false)` call that sets the Clipping rectangle to limit the area redrawn.